# how can I stop people from downloading my Assets

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, encryption, authorization

I have a bunch of 3D models on my web app and they are accessible to public to see but I don't want anyone to download them. I use Amazon S3. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If the public can see them then how can you prevent them from being downloaded. "Seeing" them means they are already downloaded.

Comment: You can use Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs to control access, but if you want the files to be 'public' then it means they can be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In the default web app - as already commented - if the client can "see" the resource, it is already on the client's side.

There are two aspects of the question. You want to prevent accessing the models from the public (unauthenticated) client or even the authenticated.

To prevent unauthorised access to S3 resources used for web apps, the common option is using the pre-signed S3 url. The application generates temporary resource link only for authorized users.

If you want to prevent access to resources even authorized users, to you can render the view on the server side e.g. see AWS AppStream